# Number of bytes in byte array

Tags: java, arrays, sizeof

I have an array `byte[] arr`;

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] arr = out.toByteArray();
```

How can I measure the data size in arr (if it was written to disk or transferred via network)?
Are below approaches are correct - they suppose that `sizeof(byte) = 1B`

```
int byteCount = out.size();
int byteMsgCount = arr.length;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, by definition the size of a variable of type `byte` is one byte. So the length of your array is indeed `array.length` bytes.

`out.size()` will give you the same value, i.e. the number of bytes that you wrote into the output stream.

[Edit] From cricket_007 comment: if you look at the implementation of `size` and `toByteArray`

```
public synchronized byte toByteArray()[] {
    return Arrays.copyOf(buf, count);
}

public synchronized int size() {
    return count;
}
```

... so `toByteArray` basically copies the current output buffer, up to `count` bytes. So **using `size` is a better solution.**

Comment: If you inspect the source code for `toByteArray()`, it will return a new array up to the value of the return value of `size()`, so unless the array is needed, then `size()` would be the preferred method call.